# Why is my angular method not receiving anything from signalr

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, signalr

Here is my hub code:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace Voting.Hubs
{
    public class VotingHub: Hub
    {
        private static readonly IHubContext HubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<VotingHub>();

        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, Context.Request.Url.Host);
            return base.OnConnected();
        }

        public static void SendVotingResults(string channel, string content)
        {
            HubContext.Clients.Group(channel).votingResultMessage(content);
        }
    }
}
```

I call this from my API like this:

```
VotingHub.SendVotingResults(Request.Headers["Host"], GenerateJson(result));
```

In angular I have the following factory:

```
app.factory('backendHubProxy', ['$rootScope',
  function ($rootScope) {

      function backendFactory(hubName) {
          var host = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname;

          var connection = $.hubConnection(host);
          var proxy = connection.createHubProxy(hubName);
          connection.start().done(function () { });

          return {
              on: function (eventName, callback) {
                  proxy.on(eventName, function (result) {
                      $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                          if (callback) {
                              callback(result);
                          }
                      });
                  });
              }
          };
      };

      return backendFactory;
  }]);
```

Then in my angular controller I'm using this code to set it up:

```
    var votingHub = backendHubProxy('votingHub');
    votingHub.on('votingResultMessage', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

The "Hub.OnConnect" does not seem to be called, even though my developer tools logs

```
/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=9BlaqaLwJnMVduhWpMeQ0H0k0R5gV7rrHCQEdn5IV0KRRyRRD5C83v2AGQPXPzCLtMdAy5Tbus416oHgK%2FuAtPZYDRtiJw51reJKuq1kOcHu%2F5Hp9krbq1VmT8eZekjd&connectionData=%5B%5D&tid=0
/signalr/start?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=9BlaqaLwJnMVduhWpMeQ0H0k0R5gV7rrHCQEdn5IV0KRRyRRD5C83v2AGQPXPzCLtMdAy5Tbus416oHgK%2FuAtPZYDRtiJw51reJKuq1kOcHu%2F5Hp9krbq1VmT8eZekjd&connectionData=%5B%5D&_=1490614124062
```

The last call's response is: { "Response": "started" }

Calling the SendVotingResults works just fine on the server, but the client never receives anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way of solving this, it does require a separate function for all channels you want to subscribe to on the server, but at least it works. I'm still unable to figure out why the code above isn't working.

```
app.service("signalrService", ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    this.votingResultMessages = function (callback) {
        var hub = $.connection.votingHub;
        $.extend(hub.client, {
            votingResultMessage: function(data) {
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        if (callback)
                            callback(data);
                    }
                );
            }

        });
        $.connection.hub.start(function () { });
    }
}]);
```

And you call the service like this:

```
signalrService.votingResultMessages(function (data) {
                        scope.voteResults = data.ResolutionDetail;
                    });
```